# Metrics on $G/K$

Tags: metric-spaces, lie-groups, topological-groups, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be a locally compact group and $K$ a maximal compact subgroup. Let $d$ be a metric distance on $G$ that is left-invariant. We may then assume it's $K$-right-invariant and if $G$ where also a Lie group then using the Lie algebra we can construct a left-invariant metric on $G/K$. In general, this does not seem to be possible. Are there any other significant or well-known cases when it is possible to define a left-invariant metric on $G/K$? Say, for $G(\mathbb{Q}_p)$  ($G$ an algebraic group)?

Comment: If it's $K$-right-invariant and $G$-left-invariant, then why doesn't it automatically descend to a left-invariant metric on $G/K$? For any $f,g,h\in G$ we should have: $d(f\cdot(g+K), f\cdot(h+K)) = d(f\cdot g, f\cdot h) = d(g,h)$ (use right-invariance of distance by $K$ in first step and left-invariance of distance by $G$ in second step).

Comment: That is not well-defined as a metric to begin with. Supose $gK=g'K$ and $hK=h'K$, then $g=g'k_1$ and $h=h'k_2$, so $d(g,h)=d(g'k_1,h'k_2)=d(g',h'k_2{k_1}^{-1})\neq d(g',h')$